# How to store a boolean mask as an attribute of a Cython class?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, cython

I failed to save a boolean mask as an attribute of a Cython class. In the real code I need this mask to perform tasks more efficiently. Here it follows a sample code:

## core.pyx

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MyClass():
    cdef public np.uint8_t[:] mask # uint8 has the same data structure of a boolean array
    cdef public np.float64_t[:] data

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.data = np.random.rand(size).astype(np.float64)
        self.mask = np.zeros(size, np.uint8)
```

## script.py

```
import numpy as np
import pyximport
pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs': np.get_include()})

from core import MyClass

mc = MyClass(1000000)
mc.mask = np.asarray(mc.data) > 0.5
```

## Error

When I run `script.py` it successfully compiles Cython, but throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    mc.mask = np.asarray(mc.data) > 0.5
  File "core.pyx", line 6, in core.MyClass.mask.__set__
    cdef public np.uint8_t[:] mask
ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('?')
```

## Workaround

My current workaround is to pass the mask to all functions where I need, using `cast=True`, for example:

```
cpdef func(MyClass mc, np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=1, cast=True] mask):
    return np.asarray(mc.data)[mask]
```

## Question

Are there any ideas out there on how the mask could be stored in the Cython class?

Answer (score 2):

So I don't believe memoryviews actually support boolean indexing anyway. Therefore to index the array you're always going to have to do

```
np.asarray(mc.data)[mask]
# or
mc.data.base[mask] # if you're sure it's always a view of something that supports boolean indexing)
```

I don't think this will change with the Cython update that @ead mentions. I suspect the reason for this is that it's probably fairly easy to do assignment (`mc.data[mask] = x`), but it isn't obvious what type should be returned by `mc.data[mask]` - it isn't a memoryview.

Therefore, whatever you do is going to involve some messy code.

---

For the part of the Assignment to the memoryview can be done with

```
mc.mask = (np.asarray(mc.data) > 0.5).view(np.uint8)
```

and returning it to a Numpy bool array with:

```
np.asarray(mc.mask).view(np.bool)
```

neither of which should involve copying.

---

If it were me designing this I'd keep the memoryviews non-public (for Cython-only use) and have normal object attributes that just hold the underlying Numpy arrays for the Python interface. You could use `property` to keep them in-sync (and do the casting):

```
cdef class MyClass:
    cdef np.uint8_t[:] mask_mview
    cdef object _mask

    @property
    def mask(self):
        return np.asarray(self._mask).view(np.bool)

    @mask.setter
    def mask(self, value):
        self._mask = value
        self.mask_view = value.view(np.uint8)

    # and the same for data
```

That way you have a memoryview to use for things that memoryviews are good at (iterating quickly element-by-element in Cython), access to the plain Numpy array for Python, and the two are held in sync (at least by the Python interface).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option (if you don’t want to use the workaround) is probably to wait for Cython 0.29.14 to be released. This hiccup [was fixed](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2675) and will be probably part of [0.29.14](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#02914-2019--).

The following minimal example

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cdef np.uint8_t[:] mask  = np.random.rand(20)>.5
```

will fail to import with the usual

> ValueError: Does not understand character buffer dtype format string ('?')

for Cython 0.29.13, but work with the current state from [0.29.x-branch on github](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/0.29.x) (or master).

Comment: That's great to hear, the workaround that keeps carrying these masks around is quite annoying, thanks

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro If it helps `mc.mask = (np.asarray(mc.data) > 0.5).view(np.uint8_t)` should assign correctly (as a different workaround)

Comment: @DavidW that seems promising, could you elaborate as a new answer? Can you use the mask stored like this for fancy indexing?